# Workaround for temporary Table in view SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, resultset, temp-tables

I have the following problem: I want to create a view that contains among others a table, whose column 'verylongtext' should be split in strings that mustn't exceed 50 characters.
   this result set should be joined in the view. 
   the temporary table would be created the following way:

```
create table #results(id int, string varchar(400))
declare @results table(id int, string varchar(400))
declare @id int
declare @strings varchar(400)
set @id = 0
while exists (select * from roottable where row_id > @id)
begin
    select top 1 @id = row_id, @strings = verylongtext from roottable
    where row_id > @id
    order by row_id asc
    insert into #results
    select @id, data from dbo.Split( [dbo].[DelineateEachNth](@strings, 50, '$'), '$')
end
```

The problem is of course, that no temporary tables are allowed in views. CTEs don't seem to work with the resultset of the function.  Is there any possible other way? I am absolutely clueless. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might not require a while loop for your requirement... It is of bad design... You might require directly a select query which you can fit directly in a view..

Comment: Please put together a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) so that people have something to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your split function directly on the base table using `APPLY`, meaning no temp table or loops are required:

```
SELECT r.id, s.data 
FROM  RootTable AS r
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(dbo.DelineateEachNth(r.VeryLongText, 50, '$'), '$') AS s;
```

You may find the scalar function `dbo.DelineateEachNth` is a performance killer (as all scalar UDFs are), as such an alternative way to split the string is to use a tally table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FixedLengthSplit
(
   @String      NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Length      INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
(   WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1), (1)) n (N)),
    N2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 a CROSS JOIN N1 b),
    N3(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 a CROSS JOIN N2 b),
    N4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N3 a CROSS JOIN N3 b),
    Numbers (N) AS 
    (   SELECT TOP (CONVERT(INT, CEILING(1.0 * ISNULL(LEN(@String),1) / @Length))) 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
        FROM n4
    )
    SELECT  ItemNumber = N + 1,
            Data = SUBSTRING(@String, 1 + (@Length * N), @Length)
    FROM    Numbers
);
```

Then your view is just:

```
SELECT *
FROM rootTable AS r
CROSS APPLY dbo.FixedLengthSplit(r.VeryLongString, 50) AS s;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your solution and the recommendation of the fixedlengthsplit function!! I did not know APPLY.